# URL Regular Expression with Perl

Tags: perl, url

I need to normalise my URL before I store it in the database using Perl regular expressions.

Here are some example URLs:

- http://www.codeme.com:80/foo/../index.php
- http://www.codeme.com:123/../foo//bar.html

However, whenever I try the below code, instead of just removing the `//` after foo in
`foo//`, it will also remove the double slash in `http://`. I need to keep the `//` in `http://`, but I don’t need the forward `//` after the `foo//`. I also need to get rid of all the `/../` or `/./` that can appear any where in the URL.

Basically, this:

```
"http://www.codeme.com:123/../foo//bar.html"
```

Should become this:

```
"http://www.codeme.com/foo/"
```

I am very new to Perl I always ignored it and thought that i will never need it however life has proven me wrong. I therefore would really appreciate your help if you can lead me to the right track.

```
sub main
{
        my $line;  
        open(FH, "test.txt");

        until(($line = <FH>) =~ /9/) {

           $line =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;

           $line =~  s|//|/| ;

           $line =~  s|\:\d\d\d|| ; 

           $line =~  s|:80||;   

            print $line;   
        }

        close FH;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the normalization you're looking to accomplish is at all clear. `www.codeme.com:123` does not normalize to `www.codeme.com`. `/../foo//bar.html` does not normalize to `/foo`. `/..//foo/bar.html` normalizes to `/`. perhaps you should try to elaborate what you're trying to accomplish since it appears to be non-standard.

Comment: You can't really do this. The URL path is not really a filesystem path and you shouldn't assume that it maps directly to a file. You might want to do a HEAD request and see what the Location header says instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the URI module. It will make your life much better and it should be included with Perl by default.

http://metacpan.org/pod/URI

```
use URI;

my $line;  
open(FH, "test.txt");

until(($line = <FH>) =~ /9/) { 
     chomp($line); # gets rid of the newline character
     my $url = new URI($line);
     print $url->scheme,'://',$url->host,'/',$url->path;
}
```

It should clean up the url pieces for you.

Also you really don't need `sub main`. In perl it's implicit.

**Edit** As @spyroboy pointed out this will not normalize the URL for you. You will still need to normalize the parts through some means but what you want to do with normalization isn't all that clear.

Comment: unfortunately, the URI module does not do any normalization.

Comment: That is because you have distinct URIs that happen to cause the server to serve up the same content.

Comment: @spyroboy what OP wants to do with normalization isn't really all that clear. This solves the immediate problem of cleaning up the URL and getting it into parts which should make it easier to normalize. I'll edit my post to clarify that.

Comment: The OP clearly wanted to remove all multiple slashes and "get rid of all the /../ or /./ that can appear any where in the URL". This does neither. It also reinvents URI's own `as_string` method.

Comment: I was hoping some one can help me do this manually rather then using URI cause it looks like my perl does not support this. i just want if i input something like this "http://www.codeme.com:123/../foo//bar.html" i can out put somthing like this "http://www.codeme.com/foo/" thats all. please i need it manually if possible. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @user1254916 - if URI isn't installed it's trivial to add it. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The `URI` module, documented [here](https://metacpan.org/module/URI), is the right way to go. It allows you to separate the URL into its component parts and adjust them separately. This Perl program seems to do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

for (
    'http://www.codeme.com:80/foo/../index.php',
    'http://www.codeme.com:123/../foo//bar.html' ) {

  my $uri = URI->new($_);

  $uri->port(80);

  my @path = $uri->path_segments;
  @path = grep /[^.]/, @path;
  $path[-1] = '' if grep $path[-1] eq $_, qw/ default.htm index.php /;
  $uri->path_segments(@path);

  print $uri->canonical, "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
http://www.codeme.com/foo/
http://www.codeme.com/foo/bar.html
```

Comment: Thank you all for your support. i just have one more request if specially to Borodin. How can i remove the default directory indexes defualt.htm or the index.php at the end. thank you very much again.

Comment: @user1254916: to remove specific items from the end of the URL just check the last element of the path and if it is unwanted then set it to the null string. I have modified my answer to demonstrate.